# Laravel Model::create mass assignment not working for columns with null as default value

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a table in my db where some columns are nullable and of course have null as default value.

In my controller, I use `Model::create($request->all())` to save. While it saves the data, the nullable columns were not populated with any value, still null.

Perhaps, does making it `->nullable()` in migration the issue?

If not, can someone explain why the nullable columns were not populated with their corresponding values? and how do I address the problem?

Comment: Can you share your model code? Are the attributes "fillable"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take look at the [Mass Assignment Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-assignment)

> So, to get started, you should define which model attributes you want to make mass assignable. You may do this using the $fillable property on the model

You have to add `$fillable` property to your model, especially when you are using `Model::create($request->all())`.

```
public $fillable = [];
```

For example:

```
public $fillable = ['some_property', 'some_other'];
```

Now, if you will call `create` method, `'some_property'` and `'some_other'` will be assigned.

Also, you can use `$guarded` which says that all properies are mass assignable and nothing is guarded

```
public $guarded= [];
```

> Don't use `$guarded` if you are going to create model by passing `$request->all()` to create method